# Fill text in custom shapes

Tags: html

I want to design a page in which I am creating a div which contains a paragraph  and an img tag which has an image 
I wish to create a layout in which I want that the image is surrounded by paragraph so is there any way to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `float` was originally created for. If you float your image, the text will wrap around it.

```
<img class="floated-image" src="source_to_image.jpg" alt="my image">
<p>This is so cool</p>
```

Then use CSS to float the image:

```
.floated-image {
  float: left;
}
```

**[Check out this working example!](http://jsfiddle.net/jc2ma51c/3/)**